# Convert the following expression to product-of-sum (POS) form

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Convert the following expression to product-of-sum (POS) form:
a.  AB + CD(AB̅ + CD)
b.  AB(B̅C̅ + BD)

I'm trying to understand how you apply boolean algebra rules and convert these into product-of-sum form.

Comment: What have you tried?  Try writing the full karnaugh map and see what you get.

Comment: We were told not use karnaugh map. This is where I'm stuck for (a) =AB +AB'CD + CCDD = AB + AB'CD + CD          --- Not sure this is right approach

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ⋅ operator represents binary conjunction, the + binary disjunction and the ‾ or the ¬ unary negation, you can apply the laws of [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) this way:

```
a·b + c·d·(a·¬b + c·d)
a·b + c·d·a·¬b + c·d·c·d  //distributivity: c·d·(a·¬b + c·d) = c·d·a·¬b + c·d·c·d
a·b + c·d·a·¬b + c·d      //idempotence of ·: c·d·c·d = c·d
a·b + c·d·(a·¬b + 1)      //distributivity: c·d·a·¬b + c·d = c·d·(a·¬b + 1)
a·b + c·d·1               //annihilator for +: (a·¬b + 1) = 1
a·b + c·d                 //identity for ·: c·d·1 = c·d; also minimal DNF
(a·b) + (c·d)
(a+c)·(a+d)·(b+c)·(b+d)   //distributivity of + over ·

(a+c)·(a+d)·(b+c)·(b+d)   //minimal CNF
```

The second expression can be simplified to it's POS form like this:

```
a·b·(¬b·¬c + b·d)
a·b·¬b·¬c + a·b·b·d)      //distributivity of · over +
a·(b·¬b)·¬c + a·b·d       //idempotence of ·: a·b·b·d = a·b·d
a·(0)·¬c + a·b·d          //complementation: b·¬b = 0
0 + a·b·d                 //annihilator for ·: a·(0)·¬c = 0
a·b·d                     //identity for +: 0 + a·b·d = a·b·d

a·b·d                     //both minimal DNF and minimal CNF
```